# Can't use IDistributedCache to cache AuthenticateResult entries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, caching, .net-core, jwt

If we ever wish to cache JSON Web Tokens, we can use an `IMemoryCache` implementation and just store the result of `JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()`, which is the type `AuthenticateResult`.

The problem is that unlike `IMemoryCache` that actually stores a reference to an object, `IDistributedCache` stores a `byte[]`, meaning we need to use serialization to store an object in that form.

`IDistributedCache` already has extension methods for serializing a string to a byte array, so all we need to do then is use any JSON serializer to serialize/de-serialze the data.

When serializing the `AuthenticateResult` object, all is good. But the issue comes when we want to de-serialize it. `AuthenticateResult` has no `public` parameterless constructor, meaning we can't actually get an instance of `AuthenticateResult` back, even though it has successfully been stored in the cache.

Is there a workaround to this, or for such caching scenarios, we are always forced to stick with an `IMemoryCache` implementation?

Comment: Have you tried MessagePack for serialization? It can handle objects without public parameterless constructor.

Comment: I would recommend creating your own class to model the result, and serialize _that_. Otherwise you're tying yourself to framework implementation details, which may change in future versions and cause incompatibilities between what's in your cache and what's in your application code if you upgrade to a new version of ASP.NET Core in the future. The fact `AuthenticateResult` isn't usable in this way is a good indicator it's not a good idea to try and do so.

Comment: @L01NL I get the following exception when using MessacePack: `FormatterNotRegisteredException: AuthenticateResult is not registered in resolver`

Comment: @MartinCostello Ignore my previous statement, a class wrapper does not fix the problem. I'll have to boil it down to things from which I can create an `AuthenticateResult`, and I'm not sure that's possible, yet.

Comment: I didn't mean a wrapper, I meant an entirely different class that represents the same state.